# is it possible to have a full url route to a anchored element on the same page?

Tags: angularjs

I have `html5mode(true)` set in my app and all of my content is in one single view.

The idea pre angular was users would click on **About** and it would scroll to the `#about` element. This works great with jquery as you can easily animate the scrolling and make it nice and fluid.

angularjs however i'm struggling how I can accomplish this using routes, and still retain that jquery slide interaction, without reloading the template/view defined in my routes.

Ideally, i'd like to have urls such as `example.com/about`, `example.com/contact` and have them behind the scenes just scroll to that element.

I have no clue how to go about this the best way considering angularjs.

Any help?

**edit:**
here is what i've tried so far and it seems to be somewhat working without animations..

in my NavigationController i have the following..

```
$scope.scrollTo = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(e, n, c){
  e.preventDefault();
  $location.hash('about');
  $anchorScroll();
});
```

However this only works if a user clicks on the button on the page, and doesn't take the URL into account at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?
http://plnkr.co/edit/De6bBrkHpojgAbEvHszu?p=preview

(not my code)

The anchor is included in the url,

`<a href="#test?scrollTo=foo">Test / Foo</a>
<a href="#weee?scrollTo=bar">Weee / Bar</a>`

and the run function on the module does the hash trick ..

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
    $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
    $anchorScroll();  
  });
})
```

Hope this helps you ..